# React-native-dotenv path could not be found within the project or in these directories:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Ive installed react-native-dotenv in my `react-native-project` (non expo) and Im getting this error

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module path from C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\node_modules\react-native-dotenv\index.js: path could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ..\..\..\..\..\node_modules
  1 | const {readFileSync, statSync} = require('fs')
> 2 | const path = require('path')
    |                       ^
  3 | const dotenv = require('dotenv')
  4 |
  5 | function parseDotenvFile(path, verbose = false) {
```

Read up online and people say you need to modify your `babel.config` in which I did

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module:react-native-dotenv',
      {
        envName: 'APP_ENV',
        moduleName: '@env',
        path: '.env',
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

But it still reproduces the same error and most of these fixes are for expo, Ive never worked with expo and I tried the following

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64227089/5413196

https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/wiki/Migration-Guide

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29314

And I am still getting the same error, could someone please advise how to fix ?

Comment: https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/issues/20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-native-dotenv` author here: as said in the comment above, Babel config looks great. Make sure to install the lib as a dev dependency.

Comment: Installed it as devDependcy still got errors only when building though.

Comment: I will push a fix today. I think I know what the issue is. Someone posted a similar issue Monday and I'm tracking it

Comment: Hi Kemal, it was me who raised it.

Comment: which babel lib do I need to install?

Comment: I'm still having this same issue in 2023.

Comment: @PunterBad the above issue has been resolved, so please raise a new issue on Github

Comment: @KemalAhmed Thanks but I'm not using it anymore.

Comment: @PunterBad sorry to hear it didn't work for you but I'm glad you were able to find something you needed. I hope I can help if any future issues come up.

Answer (score 0):

Need to run this command:

`yarn add path fs dotenv`

Looked everywhere for this error, but this is what my senior told me and
it worked for me